# ElasticSearch: advanced search inside the array of objects

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, search-engine

Let's assume that I have the following documents stored in Elasticsearch:

```
{
  id: '349dec5f-4ddf-4faa-beb0-79a0ea08bad6',
  name: 'Iphone 13',
  criteria: [
    {
      name: 'color',
      options: ['Midnight', 'Blue', 'Green'],
    },
  ]
},
{
  id: '1a63de5a-4335-4e0d-83ab-c820d57709bd',
  name: 'IPhone 14',
  criteria: [
    {
      name: 'color',
      options: ['Midnight', 'Purple', 'Red'],
    },
    {
      name: 'size',
      options: ['128GB', '256GB'],
    },
  ]
},
{
  id: 'eae5672f-2153-4f7d-be68-122e6d9fe5e1',
  name: 'Iphone 14 Pro',
  criteria: [
    {
      name: 'color',
      options: ['Black', 'Blue', 'Red'],
    },
    {
      name: 'size',
      options: ['64GB', '128GB', '256GB'],
    },
  ]
}
```

And I have the following type mappings for these documents:

```
"properties": {
  "id": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 36 },
  "name": { "type": "text" },
  "category": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 36 },
  "criteria": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "name": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 500 },
      "options": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 500 }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `criteria` is a nested array of objects with two fields `criteria.name` and `criteria.options`, so it can have not only `color` and `size`, but other values as well.

And I want to filter these documents by particular `color` and `size`, for example, when I get the following `filter` object in an HTTP request:

```
{
  search: null,
  filter: {
    criteria: [
      {
        name: 'color',
        options: ['Blue', 'Red'],
        operator: 'OR'
      },
      {
        name: 'size',
        options: ['64GB', '128GB'],
        operator: 'OR'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to get documents that have `'Blue'` or `'Red'` color AND `'64GB'` OR `'128GB'` size, so, it looks something like this:

```
if criteria.name == 'color' THEN
  criteria.options should include one of ['Blue', 'Red']
if criteria.name == 'size' THEN
  criteria.options should include one of ['64GB', '128GB']
```

So, for example, for the above `filter` object in the response, I should return two documents, the first with `name: 'IPhone 14'` and the second with `name: 'Iphone 14 Pro'` because the first one (`name: 'IPhone 14'`) has a "Red" color and a size of "128GB", and the second (`name: 'Iphone 14 Pro'`) has both "Blue" and "Red" colors and both "64GB" and "128 GB" sizes.

So, my question is how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use [Nested Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "criteria",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "criteria.name": "color"
                    }
                  }
                ], 
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "criteria.options": [
                        "Blue",
                        "Red"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "criteria",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "criteria.name": "size"
                    }
                  }
                ], 
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "criteria.options": [
                        "64GB",
                        "128GB"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```